# Find polygons that contain a specific number of points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, polygon, point-in-polygon, spatial-join

I want to make a polygon selection based on a specific number of points.
For example, I want to select those polygons that contain more than 30 points. I don't want to select every polygon that contains a point.

I tried to do something with ArcGis's data reviewer and I checked spatial join but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Could you clarify? You say you want to select polygons which contain more than 30 points from some other layer and then you say you do not want to select polygons?

Comment: Are you looking for a Python solution?

Comment: yes why not. Do you have something in mind?

Comment: There isn't a 1 step solution, combine http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58485/how-to-count-points-in-shapefile-within-polygons-of-another-shapefile with Branco's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here is a way to do it that isn't too complicated.

Create a new short integer field in your points layer.

Assign each feature a value of 1.

Spatial join your polygon layer to your points layer.

For your options, choose that *each polygon will be given a summary of the numeric attributes....*  option and summarize the values by **Sum**.

In your new layer, look for those who have the summed value of 30 or more.

Then you can export those selected features into a new layer.  To select features from your original layer, do a *select by location* query against this exported layer, and you should have it.

Comment: right idea, but can be even simpler: [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000) creates a field automatically called `Join_Count`, which is the number of times the Join Features (the points) intersect the Target Features (the polygons). (NB: other relationships besides /intersect/ can be used.). Also, you don't need to export, just use a *Definition Query* on the Spatial Join result to select only Join_Count > 30; see [Displaying a subset of features in a layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002z000000)

Comment: Branco nice idea. Thx. But I think Matt is correct! I 'll try it. Furthermore I'll try to create a tool with model builder In order to select and export the polygons with a suitable  expression.  I don't know if I can upload files thought